# Extracting raw data from a graph

Tags: visualization, data-sets

I am supposed to do black-box modeling, I need the input and output data for training, however, the authors didn't agree to share the raw data with me, I can only use their publication where these attached images are given below. Of course, I do understand the curve, however, I don't know how to create raw data from figures, is it could be achieved, if so what could be the easiest approach to have raw data from figures.

[image]

Comment: yes, you can do that! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14437/software-needed-to-scrape-data-from-graph

Comment: Great! Thanks so much! I will check

Comment: Engauge Digitizer this one is working fine with Linux since Digitize has some commands are deprecated.